# Bootstrap and D3 problems

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I use a D3 Chart with Bootstrap, however I have a problem. When I resize the window the chart doesn't resize. I took a screenshot so you can see what I mean.
I coded the container the col. everything but something won´t work.
I recognized if I refresh the page AFTER resizing the window it works.
I´d appreciate some advice or maybe a new way how to make a D3 Chart responsive.
Here is a painting that you understand what I mean.
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/7vlemu

Comment: Sorry but hard to tell the problem without seeing your code or demo.

Comment: I´d like to add the code but I´m legally not allowed to post any snippet

Comment: You could add a link to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your chart to be responsive and you are already that far that if you refresh the page after you resize the window, the chart has adjusted. That means you are already using scales and you calculated the width and the height of the svg in function of its container element which has its width in %.

The next step to truly have that responsive feel is redrawing your chart on a window resize event.

If I am not mistaken, this is how you would do it:

```
d3.select(window).on("resize",myResizeFunction);

function myResizeFunction() {
  //If you have multiple svg's, please change the selector ;-)
  d3.select("svg").remove() //remove the old chart first

 //redraw the chart here.

}
```

**EDIT** 
Ok, so here is an example:

```
function createAdaptiveBarchart(){
//this code is actually in a separate file. It draws the initial barchart
//based on the width of its containing element, which is a div in my case 
// with the id = barchart
// The div has a css width expressed in percentage.

var barchartContainer = d3.select("#barchart");

        var chartWidth = parseInt(barchartContainer.style("width"),10);     
        var chartHeight = chartWidth * this.width_height_ratio; 
        var sideMargin = Math.round(chartWidth * this.marginfactor);
        var bottomMargin = Math.round(chartHeight * 0.3);
        var fontsize = (chartWidth/this.font_to_width_ratio) + "em";


        var svg = barchartContainer.append("svg")
                                .attr({
                                    width:chartWidth,
                                    height:chartHeight
                                });


        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                .domain(mydata) 
                                .rangeRoundBands([sideMargin, chartWidth - sideMargin], .1);
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                .domain([1, d3.max(monthsarray, function(d){return d.amountMonths;})]) 
                                .range([chartHeight - bottomMargin, sideMargin]); 
        drawChart();

        function drawChart() {
            var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
                                .data(monthsarray)
                                .enter()
                                .append("g")
                                    .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + xScale(d.turnover) + ",2)";})
                                .append("rect")
                                    .attr({
                                            x:0, 
                                            y:function(d){return yScale(d.amountMonths);},
                                            width:xScale.rangeBand(),
                                            height:function(d){ return chartHeight - bottomMargin - yScale(d.amountMonths);},
                                            fill:"rgba(85, 214, 221, 0.1)",
                                            stroke:"#00ffff"
                                        });
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(xScale)
                            .orient("bottom");

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(yScale)
                            .orient("left");

            svg.append("g")
                    .attr("transform",function(){return "translate(0," + (chartHeight - bottomMargin + 3) + ")"; })
                    .attr("class","axis")
                    .call(xAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")  
                        .style("text-anchor", "end") /*  all of this is to rotate the text a bit: first achor it, reposition, rotate */
                        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                        .attr("dy", ".15em")
                        .attr("font-size", fontsize) // making the font-size in relation to the svg width;
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return "rotate(-65)" 
                            });

            svg.append("g")
                    .attr("transform","translate(" + sideMargin + ",3)")
                    .attr("class","axis")
                    .call(yAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")
                        .attr("font-size", fontsize);

};

/* THIS IS THEN THE CODE WHICH IS IN MY HTML FILE */

<script>

        createAdaptiveBarchart(); //the function I declared above

        d3.select(window).on("resize",resize); //capturing the resizing event

        function resize() {
            /* resetting the visualisation */
            d3.selectAll("svg").remove();           
            createAdaptiveBarchart();
        }


    </script>
```

That should basically do it. I would advise to try and understand the example. Since this is a piece of a larger visualisation of mine, there might be some variables in there that will not be defined if you just copy the code. But basically this example can be broken down as following:

- a standard function creating a barchart. Make sure that the width is
  in function with the width of the containing element and make your
  chart height in function of the chart width (That is what the
  width_height_ratio variable does).
- use that function to create the barchart.
- capture the window resize event
- in that event, create a callback function that removes your chart or any other appended element.
- use your standard function for creating a barchart in the callback.

If you got more questions, please shoot. The example should be online soon, i could give a link when it's up.

Comment: Thanks alot an example would be awesome

Comment: Sure, i ll look into it as soon as I am home.

Comment: I have added an example to my answer. I hope it's a bit clear :-)